# using parameter store values in apprunner

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

[image]

I'm using aws copilot but i think i can generalize this question to apprunner. trying to get envvars set from Parameter Store but having no luck. the left is my aws copilot manifest yml, i saw examples of setting things this way. it results in an apprunner configed on the right. in production it seems these are interpreted as literals and not as parameter store values

any idea on how to properly connect apprunner to parameter store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately currently App Runner doesn't provide an intrinsic way for integrating with SSM parameter store like what ECS does. As a result, Copilot doesn't support `secret` section for Request-driven service as well (refer to Copilot doc [here](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/manifest/rd-web-service/)). As for environment variables, they are what you define in the manifest and will be injected as literals.

However, there is a workaround in Copilot allowing your app to use secrets stored in SSM parameter store. You can specify an [addon template](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/developing/additional-aws-resources/) (e.g., `policy.yaml`) and put it in the `copilot/${svc name}/addons/` local directory with the following template allowing the App Runner service to be able to retrieve from SSM parameter store:

```yaml
Parameters:
  App:
    Type: String
    Description: Your application's name.
  Env:
    Type: String
    Description: The environment name your service, job, or workflow is being deployed to.
  Name:
    Type: String
    Description: The name of the service, job, or workflow being deployed.

Resources:
  MySSMPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Sid: SSMActions
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - "ssm:GetParameters"
            Resource: !Sub 'arn:${AWS::Partition}:ssm:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:parameter/*'

Outputs:
  MySSMPolicyArn:
    Value: !Ref MySSMPolicy
```

After that, in your code by using AWS SDK you can call AWS SSM API to retrieve any secrets you defined before. Let me know if you have any more questions!

Comment: I went ahead with the Fargate route instead. Is the plan to have no work arounds needed for App Runner in the future?

Comment: Yes. This is not a commitment but we are tracking this feature request [here](https://github.com/aws/apprunner-roadmap/issues/6)